# How to show some property of the object that is passed in the table

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-vue

I'm using bootstrap vue and I need to pass information to a component of the data that is passed to the table.

```
<div>
    <b-table
      :items="guests"
      :fields="fields"
      :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
      striped
      responsive="sm"
    >

    <template #head(name)="scope">
        Nome
      </template>
      <template #head(email)="scope">
        E-mail
      </template>

      <template #cell(action)="row">
        <c-action-button :id="1" />
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
```

I need to pass the id of the object that is passed in the table, to pass in the action-button component

Answer (score 0):

In a **cell()** scoped slot, you have access to row *index* and *item* object.

```js
<template #cell(action)="row">
    <c-action-button :id="row.item.id" />
    // or
    <c-action-button :id="row.index" />
</template>
```

References:

- [Scoped field
  slots](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#scoped-field-slots)
- [b-table Slots
  API](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-slots)